# Which keyframing option should be chosen to animate movement and scale?

Tags: keyframes

Which keyframe from a the following list should be used for animation of moving and scaling:

List:

- Available
- Location
- Rotation
- Scaling
- Locrot
- LocRotScale
- Rot scale
- Delta location
- Delta rotation
- Delta scale
- Visual location
- Visual rotation
- Visual scaling
- Visual locrot
- Visual locrot scale
- Visual locscale
- Visual rotscale

Can you provide me with the details of the each of these as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a preset keyset  (like loc, scale) just can just add keyframes in the channels you need using "insert single keyframe"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're trying to animate but from the list you gave you probably need Location and Scaling.

One way of animating is to have an object in the position, and with the scale you want, on the part of the time line you want the animation to start from.

With the object selected, and the mouse within the viewport, press I and select Location. Repeat and select Scale.  Or you can just do it once and select Location/Rotation/Scale, even though you don't need the rotation.

Move the time slider to the part of the time line you want to end that animation on, and move your object and scale it as you want.  Then press I again and select Location and Scale again, one after the other.